# Checking multiple condition and adding to counter in java

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements

I'm tring to check multiple conditions and add to counter for each condition in Android. I'm asking if there is a better way than my solution, specifically the last 8 lines of code below. I'll write more conditions.

```
int [] bidCounter = new int[2]; 
deck = new ArrayList<>();
southdeck = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        deck.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(deck);
for (int i = 0; i<13; i++) {
    southdeck.add(deck.get(i));
}

if (playerdeck.contains(12)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (playerdeck.contains(25)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (playerdeck.contains(38)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (playerdeck.contains(51)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (!playerdeck.contains(12) && playerdeck.contains(11) && playerdeck.contains(10)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (!playerdeck.contains(25) && playerdeck.contains(24) && playerdeck.contains(23)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (!playerdeck.contains(38) && playerdeck.contains(37) && playerdeck.contains(36)) bidCounter[0] ++;
if (!playerdeck.contains(51) && playerdeck.contains(50) && playerdeck.contains(49)) bidCounter[0] ++;
```

Comment: read up about `else`

Comment: if I use "if - else if"  and if first condition is true, it will not check other conditions but what I need is to check all conditions even if more than one condition is true. Am I wrong @TimCastelijns?

Comment: you can chain many `if - else` statements as long as they are "outside" of each other, something [like this](https://ideone.com/wiIHdd).

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean, I can check these 8 conditions with only one if - else statement? @user3170251

Comment: I added a sample program in my other comment: [click me](https://ideone.com/wiIHdd) See that even though I have 2 `if -else` statements, both still run because they come one after another

Comment: OK I see what you mean... So I have to create 4 different if - else condition for these 8 lines. Not less than 4 right?

Comment: BTW, I don't need to use else.

if (playerdeck.contains(12) || !playerdeck.contains(12) && playerdeck.contains(11) && playerdeck.contains(10)) bidCounter[0] ++;

          
if (playerdeck.contains(25) || !playerdeck.contains(25) && playerdeck.contains(24) && playerdeck.contains(23)) bidCounter[0] ++;

           
if (playerdeck.contains(38) || !playerdeck.contains(38) && playerdeck.contains(37) && playerdeck.contains(36)) bidCounter[0] ++;

           
if (playerdeck.contains(51) || !playerdeck.contains(51) && playerdeck.contains(50) && playerdeck.contains(49)) bidCounter[0] ++;

Comment: that could work, yes

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your checks could be simplified using a `for` loop. As you're checking the player's hand against the presence of a defined set of values, and incrementing the counter by 1 each time you get a match, you can create an array of expected matches and iterate against them like so:

```
for (int i : new int[] { 12, 25, 38, 51 }) {
    if (playerdeck.contains(i)) bidCounter[0]++;
}
```

New check values can be added by declaring them on the right-hand side of the `for` statement.

The second part is a bit trickier, as you're asking for two values to be present and one value *not* to be present. However, assuming that you **do not** want the first value and **do** want the second and third values, you can use a two-dimensional array like so:

```
int[][] compositeCheck = new int[][] {
    { 12, 11, 10 },
    { 25, 24, 23 },
    { 38, 37, 36 },
    { 51, 50, 49 }
};

for (int[] i : compositeCheck) {
    if (!playerdeck.contains(i[0])
            && playerdeck.contains(i[1])
            && playerdeck.contains(i[2])) {
       bidCounter[0]++;
    }
}
```

tl;dr If you need to write the same code on multiple lines, chances are you can do it in some sort of loop instead.